# default values and future changes in data modeling

Tags: database, erd

i have the following 2 tables a lecturer can either be a junior lecturer or a senior lecturer depending on their years of experience. by default all lecturers are junior but this is due to change over time. i would like to know how do i represent the default value in an ERD and how will i cater for changes in future. thanks

```
create TABLE [dbo].[LecturerCategory](
    [Cat_Code] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) primary key NOT NULL,
    [Cat_Name] [varchar](50) NULL
    constraint LECT_NUM foreign key references LECTURER(LECT_NUM))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lecturer](
    [LECT_NUM] [varchar](6) primary key NOT NULL,
    [LECT_LNAME] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LECT_FNAME] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LECT_EXP] [int] NULL
    )
```

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting a typo (LETC_NUM) in your question, and adding a primary key constraint to the second table.

Comment: You need to correct your relationships before you get a correct answer on default values.  there should be a column Cat_Code in the second table that references the first table's primary key.  There should not be a column LECT_NUM in the first table that references the second table.

Comment: The syntax for default values is likely to be DBMS dependent.  ERD is DBMS independent, at least in concept.  I recommend that you learn ER diagramming and/or Relational schematic diagramming.  Then, as a final step, convert the diagram into an SQL CREATE script.